# OpenWeatherMap API - Trouble with append longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, openweathermap

I'm trying to define the search city based off the user's longitude and latitude which I'm accessing through `.geolocation`

When adding the long and lat to my url I get this error

```
cod    :    "400"    message    :    "-104.9435462 is not a float"
```

```js
getLocation();

//Find Location of Device
function getLocation(callback) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getData);
  }

}

//Get/set Variables
function getData(position) {
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var altitude = position.coords.altitude;
  var heading = position.coords.heading;
  var speed = position.coords.speed;
  var date = position.timestamp;

  getWeather(longitude, latitude);
  console.log(longitude);
  console.log(latitude);

}

//Call OpenWeatherAPI
function getWeather(x, y) {
  const apiKey = '';
  var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + x + '&lon=' + y + '&APPID=280e605c456f0ba78a519edde1a641d3';

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(result) {

    }
  });
}; //END getWeather()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you work it out ?

Comment: I did, but I went with api.wunderground.com because they have an auto locate feature in their API

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but hopefully this will save others time. The error message is misleading.

**The error occurs because the longitude, which has a range of -180 to 180, was placed in the latitude, which has a range of -90 to 90.**

In the code, getWeather() call was made like this:

```
getWeather(longitude, latitude);
```

However, notice that the latitude and longitude (x, y) are ordered (latitude, longitude) in the function:

```
  function getWeather(x, y) {
  const apiKey = '';
  var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + x + '&lon=' + y + '&APPID= removed id';
// additional code
};
```

Changing the call should resolve the problem:

```
getWeather(latitude, longitude);
```